# Cannot Get Page Parameters In SvelteKit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to get the name of a game from the page parameters. I was expecting that the load function would get the location of the game and return it to the page but instead when I ran the code below I got this error:

```
Cannot read property 'slug' of undefined
```

This is the code that I am trying to run:

```
<script context="module">
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Load} */
export async function load({ params, fetch, session, stuff }) {
    let request = await fetch("/json/games.json");
    let games = await request.json();
    let game = games[params.slug];
    if (game && game.location) {
      return {
        props: {
          game: game.location
        }
      }
    } else {
      return {
        status: 404,
        error: "The game could not be found"
      }
    }
}
</script>

<script>
   export let game;
</script>

<svelte:head>
   <title>Game</title>
</svelte:head>

<p>Location of Game:</p>
<p>{game}</p>
```

Comment: This should be working if the name and location of your page is, say, `/src/routes/games/[slug].svelte`. Is that the case?

Comment: @ThomasHennes Yes, but it is not working.

Comment: Are you using a recent svelte-kit version? Your code snippet should work in 1.0.0-next.294  (assuming we are looking at code from route file like `src/routes/game/[slug].svelte`)

Comment: As the others say: this _should_ work. Can you also provide the url in the browser and the full path of the route itself ?

Comment: @BobFanger Thanks! I upgraded SvelteKit and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was resolved by upgrading the [@sveltejs/kit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sveltejs/kit/v/next) package.